# PHP error for const array

Tags: php, arrays, syntax-error

hello in my PHP file i got error on host for this line that defines const array:

```
const telegram_methods=['sendMessage'=>'sendMessage','answerCallbackQuery'=>'answerCallbackQuery','forwardMessage'=>'forwardMessage'];
```

after some changes in host configurations. the error is:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in /........./st_datas.php on line 8
```

what is the problem of this line or host configurations?
and this post:
[PHP Parse/Syntax Errors; and How to solve them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them)
is so general and not duplicate of my question.

Comment: Constants can't be arrays, but it could be a static field instead (if in class).

Comment: make it static as constant only be use for single value reference

Comment: Ok. thanks  Nigel Ren &  Exprator. but i used this way with no problem before

Answer (score 1):

Maybe for your php version. If your php version >= 5.4, you can use brackets to define array.

So try it:

```
const telegram_methods = array('sendMessage'=>'sendMessage','answerCallbackQuery'=>'answerCallbackQuery','forwardMessage'=>'forwardMessage');
```

Comment: thanks. now this error : Arrays are not allowed in class constants in ..../st_datas.php on line 9

Comment: Unfortunately It's need php>=5.6 to define array as constant in class!

Comment: Thanks @Mohammad Hamedani. my host admin changes php version from 5.6 to 5.3 without notice to me and it was prblem

Answer (score 1):

```
const telegram_methods=array('sendMessage'=>'sendMessage','answerCallbackQuery'=>'answerCallbackQuery','forwardMessage'=>'forwardMessage');
```

Answer (score 1):

In regards to your follow up question (arrays are not allowed in class constants) it means simply as it says.

This has been updated in PHP 7 but before then if you need to set a class variable as an array simply drop the constant.

Check out the comments here for a more detailed response.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php